# so...that / to the extent that / such that do they all interchangeable?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

This is a definition of the verb "inundate".

> to give or send somebody so many things that they cannot deal with them all

I wonder if I can paraphrase it to

> to give or send somebody to the extent that they cannot deal with them all

or

> to give or send somebody such that they cannot deal with them all

In their usages, I think "so...that" and "such that" both can be used more flexibly in a sentence compared with to the extent that. do they all interchangeable when the sentence behind the phrase comes to describing result or degree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't,  because *give somebody* and *send somebody* do not mean the same as *give/send somebody **things***. You need a word for *them all* to refer to.

The literal meaning of *inundate* is *flood.*

Comment: I really appreciate all of your answers. it helps me a lot all the time. if I say "to give or send somebody things to the extent that they cannot deal with them all" or to give or send somebody things such that they cannot deal with them all" instead of the original one, would there be any semantic difference?

Comment: _Such that_ doesn't necessarily imply quantity; it could mean _things of a kind that..._ I still think the original version is best. However, if you use an uncountable noun instead of _things_  you could say _to give somebody work to the extent that they cannot deal with it all_.

Comment: when we make sentences using so...that/such that/to the extent that like above, even if their structures are different, do they mean the same in meaning? they're translated into my first language as if they have the similar meaning. If so, is it a personal preference?

Comment: _So many that_ has to be used with countable nouns - it means _such a large number_. _So much that_ refers to a large quantity, or a great degree, of something. _To the extent that_ (implying a great extent) is similar. As I said, _such that_ can mean _of a kind that_, not necessarily referring to quantity.